# Ant Design Pro login issue. Not understand the code

Tags: javascript, ant-design-pro, es6-generator

I was working Ant Design pro. But i can't understand the model of the login code. Here they use

```
effects: {
           *login({ payload }, { call, put }) {}
         }
```

if you wanted to see the full code goto this link
[Ant Design Pro login model js file](https://github.com/ant-design/ant-design-pro/blob/master/src/models/login.js)

Here you will find the full code. Now I don't understand what that code means.

Thanks

Answer (score 3):

A function name with a star means a [generator](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Guide/Iterators_and_Generators). A generator is a `function` whose running process can be paused using the `yield` keyword. [yield](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/yield) is a two-way communication between the generator and its caller. With that knowledge, let's see the function itself:

```
    *login({ payload }, { call, put }) {
      const response = yield call(fakeAccountLogin, payload);
      yield put({
        type: 'changeLoginStatus',
        payload: response,
      });
      // Login successfully
      if (response.status === 'ok') {
        reloadAuthorized();
        const urlParams = new URL(window.location.href);
        const params = getPageQuery();
        let { redirect } = params;
        if (redirect) {
          const redirectUrlParams = new URL(redirect);
          if (redirectUrlParams.origin === urlParams.origin) {
            redirect = redirect.substr(urlParams.origin.length);
            if (redirect.match(/^\/.*#/)) {
              redirect = redirect.substr(redirect.indexOf('#') + 1);
            }
          } else {
            window.location.href = redirect;
            return;
          }
        }
        yield put(routerRedux.replace(redirect || '/'));
      }
},
```

The `function` expects two objects as input and reduces them to parameters. You need to pass the first parameter as an object like `{payload: 'something'}` and the `payload` attribute of this object will be mapped into a parameter of the `function`. Similarly, the second object you pass will need a call and a put attribute, which are functions.

First it executes call, passing fakeAccountLogin and payload and yields the function, that is, the function pauses and sends the result of call to the outer scope. When the login function is resumed using the `.next()` `function` of the iterator of the generator, whatever is passed to it will be assigned to response. After this, `put` is called, passing `changeLoginStatus` as `type` and `response` as `payload` and the result if yielded to the caller of this `function`.

When the `.next()` of the iterator of this generator is called, response.status is checked against 'ok' and if there is a match, then `reloadAuthorized` is called, `urlParams` is initialized as well as `params`. After this `redirect` will be initialized with `params.redirect` and it this is truey, `redirectUrlParams` are initialized and some further URL operations will happen. Anyways, if there is a redirect, then a function ends.

If `response.status` was `'ok'`, but there was no redirect, then `put` is called and the result is yielded out of the `function` end when the next `.next()` call is issued, the `function` will end. If `response.status` was not `'ok'`, then the `function` ended much earlier, namely when the outer if was evaluated to be false.

You will need to take a look into reducing objects and arrays in Javascript as well as iterators and generator functions. You will have a difficult time until you allocate time for this, so the sooner you do it, the better. I recommend Chapter 2 and Chapter 5 of this book: https://github.com/getify/You-Dont-Know-JS/tree/master/es6%20%26%20beyond

Comment: thank you for your replay. I was really stuck in this. but why they code like this. It can be by calling function differently. Why the use yield. If you kind can u help to solve my confusion about yield!!! 
I don't find any login function by calling .next(). I understand the call() function but i don't understand the put() function.

Comment: @Arnob you are welcome. If you import this and call it Login, then you can call the login function via var myIterator = Login.effects.login(yourobject1, yourobject2); Note that this call just creates the iterator and passes the parameters to the function, the function will not start the execution yet. Only when you call myIterator.next you start the execution of the function until the first yield (or the end of the function if no yield is reached). And then each time you call next for the iterator, the function's execution is continued.

Comment: @Arnob Javascript generators are very much like state machines. The reason the login function was programmed this way is that the function will have to yield control anyway to asynchronous function, so they intended to make this readable. I know, I know it's difficult to read it, but at first traditional Javascript code was difficult to read as well. You really need to study ES6 features in order to understand this stuff. I know it's time-consuming, but you consume less time studying it than studying code written using it. I know this from my own experience.